# sails:how to store excel data into elasticserach in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, elasticsearch, sails.js

i'm working with file upload functionality and i red the excel file in json format.I need to store this json file into elastic search.how can i store that excel data into elasticsearch.

can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace'
});
client.create({
    index: 'myindex',
    type: 'mytype',
    id:2,
    body: workbook.Strings,
},function (error) {
    if (error) 
    {
        console.log('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
    } 
    else 
    {
        console.log('All is well');
    }
});
```

but i'm getting error as `elasticsearch cluster is down!
Elasticsearch TRACE: 2015-09-01T12:14:59Z`.please help me to fix this.

Comment: Might want to look into logstash with CSV filter.

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of the code you have so far? Also do you already have an existing ES instance up and running?